# How To Remove JoinPouch Pop-Ups From Showing On My Site

Tags: javascript

There extension shows content on my site and I want to block it using JavaScript.  Is there anyone that knows how to block these div classes from being created?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
function Init () {
        var body = document.body;

        if (body.addEventListener) {
            body.addEventListener ('DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument', OnNodeInsertedIntoDocument, false);
        }
    }

    function OnNodeInsertedIntoDocument () {
        var elements = ["mainPouchDiv", "pouchNotifyHeader", "nsPouchCrossPromotionContainer"];
        var element = null;
        var i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            element = document.getElementById(elements[i]);

            if (element) {
                document.body.removeChild(element);
                element = null;
            }
        }
    }
```